# Php page markup controls

Tags: php, codeigniter, replace, markup

i have a page where users put their own posts, users are able to markup their posts with tags like :

`{strong}{/strong}  or {italic}{/italic} or {title}{/title} etc ...`

the difficult for me is to make them not invading between themself.

i mean this is ok:

```
{strong}{/strong} {italic}{/italic}
```

but i need to avoid all the possible cases like these:

```
{strong}{italic}{/strong}{/italic}
{italic}{strong}{/italic}{italic}{/strong}{/italic}
{italic}{/strong}{/italic}{/strong}{/italic}
```

and so on ... really too much cases to write 1 control foreach one i think :P

the logic should be to make them always separated and remove the not needed or included tags ... hoping question is clear :P

Comment: Use a stack-based parser. Or, even better, don't reinvent the wheel and use an existing ubb code parser.

Comment: whhy? :( i would like to make it personal :(

Comment: Replacing the order of the tags is a bit tricky but to remove the extra closing tags, try using a positive behind `(?<=foo)bar` to get rid of them.

Comment: to make it personal you could just look at a previous markup and methods mimic them and change to your specifications.

Comment: and is there some php ubb to take a look? i'm not founding nothing particulary ...

Comment: ubb looks like this [b][i]test[/i][/b], it is also called BBCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to your problem is to develop a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) or a [stack based parser](http://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~jdonalds/331/lecture08.html), but is probably complete overkill for your situation.

Matching start tags with end tags is in general very similar to the language of balanced parentheses (for instance: (), (()), (()()) are balanced correctly, )(, ()(, )(()() are not).  The language of balanced parentheses is not a *regular* language, and therefore cannot be 'parsed' using regular expressions (unless you can limit the depth that they can be nested, see [here](http://www.texttoolkit.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=63%3aparsing-balanced-parenthesis-with-regular-expressions&catid=35%3atechnology&Itemid=55)).

My suggestion to you would be to convert all of your pseudo tags into actual html tags, and then parse that with [PHP's Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Comment: well i will document myself, the problem is i would like to not convert in html tags before savig into db, thx anyway!

Comment: No problem.  You can always convert back to your pseudo tags after validating.